# How to make SQL database values appear on specific parts of an app layout?

Tags: sql-server, android-studio

[screenshot of app function description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtbtS.jpg)I would like to know how to show values in the columns of my SQL database on specific views on my app and update automatically whenever the data in these columns are changed?

I haven't yet created an SQL database (Don't know how to), but I am very familiar with how it works. I have come across one tutorial on Youtube that demonstrates how to show the data on a list view, but that is not what I intend to do. I intend to show the values on specific headings and each heading displays a value received from the database.

As seen in the image provided, "Name", "Last name" and "Headshots" are hardcoded text views that will never change, they are however, names of the columns on the database, but won't need to be collected from the database via the app. The values however, are subject to change whenever the data is manipulated on the server. I need to know how to display these.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use google and find a tutorial. This is off topic at SO because this site is for questions and answers. You are looking for a how to guide. But honestly this is NOT a sql server question.

Comment: Okay, then will you be kind enough to at least direct me to a tutorial because I have been looking up and down the net all week?

Comment: Looking for tutorials is off topic here. Also, no idea what environment you are programming in. Figure out what language you are coding in and look on google. There are thousands of basic programming tutorials in every language.

Comment: Jesus, you are one cold person. Why are you even on here. Don't answer that, It's "off topic".

Comment: I am sure it is frustrating but it is clearly spelled out that asking for tutorials is considered off topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I did however find several tutorials [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=QQ1PXITwOaeKgge63oDQDQ&q=android+studio+basic+tutorial&oq=android+studio+basic+tutorial&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i20i263j0i30j0i8i30l4.18417.19480..20343...0.0..0.133.798.0j7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i8i7i30.KEwHUJpgcyo)